# App Development: Project Finalisation & Handover (iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-development

I'm uncertain if this is the right place to raise this question, please let me know if not and I'll take it down.

We have outsourced the development of an app for our company on iOS and Android. The UAT has been signed off on and the app is currently live. We are now finalising the project and they are giving us the code and such.

In general what list of documents or specific bits (API Keys, Logins) would we need to obtain from them to conclude this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to create an app developer account.
- They need to transfer the app from their to your app developer account.
- Source code, preferably as Git repository so that you also get the development history.
- All graphics source files.
- A signed document that clearly states that they have transferred everything and loose the right to use the code/ideas/trademarks/graphics/... they created/supplied.
- Make sure you have all rights (see above) if they outsourced work to other parties.
- Check the licenses for code/graphics/fonts/... that came from third parties and make ownership is transferred.
- Check the licenses of external code libraries and see if it is compatible with your use. If not, make sure they fix this. For example some licenses do not allow you to sell your software, require you to make the full app open source, require you to show the license somewhere, ...
- Get hold of accounts of backend services used.

It's very easy to forget things.

Answer (score 2):

Android:

- Android Studio Project including code and resources
- Google developer account credentials the app is currently published on. Or create your own account and transfer the app to it.
- If the app uses any libraries that require keys like Google maps or Contentful you will need all the credentials and full access to them.
- The keystore the app was signed with to be published to the store and the password for it.